# Facebook C# SDK throwing Exceptions on ParseCookieValue

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

We're using Facebook connect in an application outside of Facebook, quite regularly the C# Facebook SDK is throwing an exception with this message "Precondition failed: !cookieValue.Contains(",") Session value must not contain a comma."

After doing some research it seems linked to the fact that we're using the JavaScript SDK (for  Facebook Connect) and the C# SDK at the same time. As I'm unable to replicate the issue myself I don't have much clue.

**UPDATE**: In fact the exceptions are happening in prod to "real" users. THE SDK is throwing a hundred of them a day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in the Facebook C# SDK: http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/discussions/273578/

> Could you remove the following line of code from ParseCookieValue
>   method.
>
> Contract.Requires(!cookieValue.Contains(","), "Session value must not
>   contain a comma.");
>
> This has already been fixed in the latest v5.3.1beta
>   (http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/releases/view/75790)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah - getting this as well - also using c# SDK and Javascript SDK.

It seems to have happened ONLY to my FB account - when testing my application - and it happened after I had used the wrong app secret in my Oath settings.

It seems that Facebook had TWO access tokens for my personal account - and was trying to store them both in the cookie. I tried using  the SDK deleteauthcookie() method, I deleted ALL of Facebook cookies in my browser. No Luck.

**The only solution was to remove ALL of the cookies in my browser....**

It seems Facebook SOMETIMES tries to store two access tokens in a cookie - separating them with a comma - and c# SDK doesn't like that.